# File is cached by browser even if the response has no-cache header

Tags: http, go

```
var epoch = time.Unix(0, 0).Format(time.RFC1123)
var headers = map[string]string{
    "Expires":         epoch,
    "Cache-Control":   "no-cache, private, max-age=0",
    "Pragma":          "no-cache",
    "X-Accel-Expires": "0",
}

log.Errorln("no cache header")
for k, v := range headers {
    rw.Header().Set(k, v)
}

http.ServeFile(rw, req, path)
```

I have the above code block in my server side to serve file requests. But the files served are still cached in browser.

But instead of `http.ServeFile()` I used `http.ServeContent()` with the last modified timestamp as `time.Now()`. This works if the request has considerable time difference. Does browser give priority to last modified time than `no-cache` header? Then what is the purpose of `no-cache` header? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Without seeing what your browser sees, it would be difficult to tell you what is really happening. We would need to see the HTTP header you see in Firebug or similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers cache files without paying attention to headers. Typical solution is to add some get parameter to static file path, so the browser considered it like different request. It can be hash-sum or last modified timestamp. It might look somethind like this: `site.com/icon.png?q=123456`.